# Different behavior between different String Array initialisation

Tags: arrays, vb.net

If I fill an array like

```
Return New String() {"A", "B"}
```

and return it in a property to display its elements into a combobox

```
Public Class Test
    Public ReadOnly Property TLTeams As String()
        Get
            'Return New String() {"A", "B"}
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim t As New Test
        For i As Integer = 0 To t.TLTeams.Length
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(t.TLTeams(i).ToString)
        Next i
    End Sub
End Class
```

It works fine.
But if I change the initialization to

```
Public ReadOnly Property TLTeams As String()
    Get
        Dim a As String = "A"
        Dim b As String = "B"
        Dim ArS(1) As String
        Return ArS
    End Get
End Property
```

my combobox is empty (I dont get any error though). Could anyone explain that to me?

Comment: you never put anything in `ArS`

Comment: Why did you expect anything in your combo? You return an empty array

Comment: Dis you push the variables in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second example, if you want something to get back from the property then you need to fill the array.

```
Public ReadOnly Property TLTeams As String()
    Get
        Dim a As String = "A"
        Dim b As String = "B"
        Dim ArS(1) As String
        ArS(0) = a
        ArS(1) = b
        Return ArS
    End Get
End Property
```

However, given the context, returning a fixed set of constant strings, the first approach seems to be preferable. (Less code and the array size is calculated automatically).

If the context changes and you find yourself the need to return a variable number of strings then consider to use as a return type a `List(Of String)`

Comment: Ah ok! Thanks for your answer and especially for thinking ahead and giving me the advise for variable numbers!